# How to divide two columns which is having 0 or null values

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv below

```
ID,A,B
hi,1,0
hj,1,1
hk,1,-
hl,10,5
```

Here my expected out is

```
ID,A,B,C
hi,1,0,0
hj,1,1,1
hk,1,-,0
hl,10,5,2.0
```

How to divide `df['A'] / df['B']`?

Comment: How is 1/0 = 0 in the first row?

Comment: so 1/0 you would like 0 ? what is the math logic behind it ?

Comment: yes if we cant divide it has to 0

Comment: that do i need to write (zero division error)exeption case to print 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Use a function and use apply.

```
def my_func(x):
    try:
        return int(x['A']) / int(x['B'])
    except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
        return 0

df["C"] = df.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```

Your output dataframe now is:

```
    ID  A   B   C
0   hi  1   0   0.0
1   hj  1   1   1.0
2   hk  1   -   0.0
3   hl  10  5   2.0
```

Comment: if i am having one more column how to make that column as intact

Comment: I have edited my answer now. Check if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you would like to treat `inf` to `0`:

```
df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').eval('A/B').fillna(0).replace({np.inf:0})
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    2.0
dtype: float64
df['C']=    df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').eval('A/B').fillna(0).replace({np.inf:0})
```

Comment: if i am having one more column how to make that column as intact

Comment: @Nons assign it back ?